# How to change the background of a form to make it look like two forms?

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

Below is what I am trying to achieve: 
[image]

This is what I have so far:
[image]
I am using Drupal 7. This is the link to the test site: http://test-caal.gotpantheon.com/

It is one form that I want to make look like two. Is there a way to add a background image that would make it look like the same as what I am attempting to achieve?

Thank you for your help!

Izumi.

Comment: Umm ... considering you have two "Log in" buttons, and they are mutually exclusive (one person will only fill in one side, not both sides) then shouldn't they **actually** be two separate `<form>`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsBin demo**](http://jsbin.com/UxoFojA/1/edit)

[image]

A form allows you to use the `<fieldset></fieldset>` tags.

so something like

```
<form id="" action="" method="">    
    <fieldset>
        <!-- inputs here -->
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <!-- inputs here -->
    </fieldset>    
</form>
```

and styled accordingly, might be what you're looking for. Look at the above demo link.

```
 <form id="" action="" method="">

    <fieldset>
      <h3>Member Login</h3>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <h3>Partner Login</h3>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
    </fieldset>   

</form>
```

**Basic CSS:**

```
form h3{
  color:#fff;
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:1.4em;
  padding:10px 0;
  border-top:2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
fieldset{
  background:#589FCF;
  border: 5px solid #2E2E2E;
  width:180px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
}
form input[type=text]{
  border:0;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For what you're trying to achieve, two separate forms would be the way to go, since you have two different `sign in` buttons. Do something like this:

```
<div id="forms">
   <form id="form1">
   /*Form stuff goes here*/
   </form>
   <form id="form2">
   /*Other form goes here*/
   </form>
</div>
```

For your CSS, simply set the background of `forms` to black and the background of the other form elements to blue, or whatever color you want, here, the given color is the one in the picture.

```
#forms{
   background-color:black;
}
#form1 #form2{
    background-color:rgb(69,136,203); 
}
```